# How to use \foreach with two \pgfmathsetmacro in the list

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}


\pgfmathsetmacro{\N}{6}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\angle}{360/\N}

\tikzset{structureline/.style={black,thin}}

\draw[lightgray] (-6,-6) grid (6,6);

\filldraw[thick,fill=green!20,draw=green] 
(0,0) -- (1/3*5,0) arc[radius=1/3*5, start angle=0, end angle=\angle] node[below=0.5cm] {$\alpha = 
\angle$} -- cycle;  

\draw[->,structureline] (0,-5) -- (0,5);
\draw[->,structureline] (-5,0) -- (5,0);
\draw[structureline] (0,0) circle[radius=4];
\draw[structureline] (0,0) -- (\angle:4);
\foreach \i in {\angle,2*\angle,...,\N*\angle}{do something}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

it does not allow me to use the list as such, but it does work when I remove the " ... "

How can I fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

When you remove the `...`, it is just an explicit list.  With the `...`, it expects to find a pattern.  However, I do not believe the pattern of a `\foreach` loop can contain `tikz` arithmetic evaluations such as `\angle,2*\angle,...,\N*\angle`.

But what you can do is perform the loop with `1,2,...,\N` and incorporate `\angle` multipliers inside the loop.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\pgfmathsetmacro{\N}{6}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\angle}{360/\N}

\tikzset{structureline/.style={black,thin}}

\draw[lightgray] (-6,-6) grid (6,6);

\filldraw[thick,fill=green!20,draw=green] 
(0,0) -- (1/3*5,0) arc[radius=1/3*5, start angle=0, end angle=\angle] node[right=0.5cm] {$\alpha = 
\angle$} -- cycle;  

\draw[->,structureline] (0,-5) -- (0,5);
\draw[->,structureline] (-5,0) -- (5,0);
\draw[structureline] (0,0) circle[radius=4];
%\draw[structureline] (0,0) -- (\angle:4);
\foreach \i in {1,2,...,\N}{
  \draw[structureline] (0,0) -- (\i*\angle:4);
  \filldraw[thick,fill=red!\i0,draw=red] 
  (0,0) -- ({(\i/2)*cos((\i-1)*\angle)},{(\i/2)*sin((\i-1)*\angle)}) 
  arc[radius=(\i/2), start angle=(\i-1)*\angle, 
  end angle=(\i)*\angle] node[] {\LARGE\i} -- cycle; 
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In these cases the manual suggest to use `parse=true`.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}


\pgfmathsetmacro{\N}{6}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\angle}{360/\N}

\tikzset{structureline/.style={black,thin}}

\draw[lightgray] (-6,-6) grid (6,6);

\filldraw[thick,fill=green!20,draw=green] 
(0,0) -- (1/3*5,0) arc[radius=1/3*5, start angle=0, end angle=\angle] node[below=0.5cm] {$\alpha = 
\angle$} -- cycle;  

\draw[->,structureline] (0,-5) -- (0,5);
\draw[->,structureline] (-5,0) -- (5,0);
\draw[structureline] (0,0) circle[radius=4];
\draw[structureline] (0,0) -- (\angle:4);
\foreach \i [parse=true] in {\angle,2*\angle,...,\N*\angle}{
\node at (\i:4) {do something};
}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: macro in \foreach]

Comment: Hey, thanks a bunch! could you forward me the link to that manual?

Comment: The [PGFmanual on CTAN](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf). How do you write Ti*k*Z code without this manual?

Comment: lecture notes >.....<